# How can I query my join table (many-to-many) using Linq and EF6 (get a users roles)

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have 3 tables: `Users`, `UserRoles`, `UserRoleAssoc` (join table consists of only `UserID` and `UserRoleID`). Entity Framework does not show `UserRoleAssociations` in my model which seems correct. My goal is to return a list of the users roles. How do I get all `UserRoles` where `UserID`=UserID?

This is what I have does it look correct or is there a better way to do it? I guess I use the Navigation properties that were automatically created when I update model from db?

```
public IEnumerable<UserRole> GetUserRoles(int userID)
{
    using (var ctx = new DataEntities())
    {
        var userroles = (from ur in ctx.UserRoles
                         from ura in ur.Users.Where(x => x.UserID == userID)
                              select ur).ToList();
        return userroles;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version is essentially correct but it does over-complicate things.

Try

```
    public IEnumerable<UserRole> GetUserRoles(int userID)
    {
        using (var ctx = new DataEntities())
        {
            return ctx.Users.Where(x => x.UserID == userID)
                            .Select(x => x.UserRoles.ToList())
                            .FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Or

```
    public IEnumerable<UserRole> GetUserRoles(int userID)
    {
        using (var ctx = new DataEntities())
        {
            return ctx.UserRoles.Where(x => x.Users.Any(y => y.UserID == userID))
                                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wait can't I just do this? Does EF already return a users roles for me?`User user = User.GetByUserID(userID);
UserRoles roles = user.UserRoles;`

Comment: @user2272527 Sure, if you only need to get the UserRoles when you're getting the user. But to be safe you should execute the query right there by calling `var roles = user.UserRoles.ToList()`. Behind the scenes, the queries that get executed in this and my second example should be almost identical.

Comment: Thank you very much! Although when I try user.UserRoles.ToList() I keep getting: An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: That's because you're trying to access a navigation property after the db context has been disposed. Accessing a navigation property without first using the `Include()` extension method triggers another SQL query and doing that after the context has been disposed triggers that exception.